# Get object name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, local-storage

I want to get the name of objects in another object.
These are my objects:

```
{
"events": {
"EED8A79F-B374-4AE6-BA6F-B7B98D9D7142": {
  "name": "Defeat the renegade charr.",
  "level": 42,
  "map_id": 20,
  "flags": [],
  "location": {
    "type": "sphere",
    "center": [ -9463.6, -40310.2, -785.799 ],
    "radius": 2500,
    "rotation": 0
  }
},
"3A2B85C5-DE73-4402-BD84-8F53AA394A52": {
  "name": "Bonus Event: Cull the Flame Legion",
  "level": 80,
  "map_id": 929,
  "flags": [ "group_event" ],
  "location": {
    "type": "cylinder",
    "center": [ -38.7202, -176.915, -892.494 ],
    "height": 2027.5,
    "radius": 10314.4,
    "rotation": 0
  }
},
"CEA84FBF-2368-467C-92EA-7FA60D527C7B": {
  "name": "Find a way to open the door and escape the armory.",
  "level": 8,
  "map_id": 19,
  "flags": [ "group_event" ],
  "location": {
    "type": "poly",
    "center": [ -45685.2, -13819.6, -1113 ],
    "z_range": [ -2389, 163 ],
    "points": [
      [ -49395.8, -15845.5 ],
      [ -42699.7, -15794.1 ],
      [ -43053, -14081.4 ],
      [ -43629.7, -11725.4 ],
      [ -49647.8, -11651.7 ]
    ]
  }
},
...
}
}
```

I use this piece of code to get all the objects in the "events" object and save them in localStorage:

```
$.each(data.events, function(index, value) {
    localStorage.setItem("Event" + event_count, data.events);
    event_count++;
});
```

But now my localStorage is like this:
[image: LocalStorage after using code above]

How can I get the object names in stead of the whole object? I can get the level, map_id etc by using data.events.level, data.events.map_id but how can I get the object names, for example: "EED8A79F-B374-4AE6-BA6F-B7B98D9D7142"

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` cannot store Objects, only strings (it'll call `.toString` on anything passed that isn't a string, hence why you see `[object Object]`).

To store an object use `JSON.serialize()` to write it, and `JSON.parse()` to read it.

Within your `$.each` loop, the current event's GUID will be in the `index` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$.each(data.events, function(index, value) {
    localStorage.setItem("Event" + event_count,value.name);
    event_count++;
});
```

Comment: value.name returns the name value in the "EED8A79F-B374-4AE6-BA6F-B7B98D9D7142" object